# Long search term broke layout in Android Studio. Any way to fix this?

Tags: android-studio

I was searching a long string within the project. And as of then, each time I search something, drop-down menu is broken e.g. expanded from left to right, across both screens.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I tried highlighting the term and pressing Delete, but it did not delete the search term from the list.

I guess I will have to reset something, but I would like NOT to reset a lot of things as I've just set the Studio the way I like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AndroidStudio Preferences folder on disk, there will be an options/other.xml file; in there, under the key `<component name="FindSettings">/<option name="RECENT_FIND_STRINGS">` you'll find the offender. Exit Android Studio, edit that file, and relaunch.